# How to extract a column from HTML into a list?

Tags: python, html, regex, beautifulsoup

I need to extract a list of country names from an HTML document, but I am getting the entire line of HTML code rather than just the name I need in my `list`.

Below is a function I have written that accomplishes this task, but I am not getting the list I need:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


country_list = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(html), 'lxml')

for idx in soup.find_all('a', class_="metaLink"):
#   re.sub('<.*?>', '', soup)
    country_list.append(idx)
return country_list
```

The variable (`html`) is an external html file and I should be returning a list of country names.  Instead the items in the list I am returning are in this format.

```html
<a class="metaLink" href="javascript:void(0)" 
   onclick="loadMetaData('AFG', 'C' ,'Country', 'Afghanistan')">Afghanistan</a>
```

The list has several hundred items that appear this way, but all I need is the country name, in this case, `'Afghanistan'` is the only word I need.

How do I remove the remaining text of the HTML code?  I have tried using the regular expression that I have commented out, but I don't believe I am using it in the correct place.

Comment: You do not need a regex, just replace `country_list.append(idx)` with `country_list.append(idx.string)` or `country_list.append(idx.text)`

Comment: What are you getting back that is in idx ? is it something like this `<a class="metaLink" href="javascript:void(0)" 
   onclick="loadMetaData('AFG', 'C' ,'Country', 'Afghanistan')">Afghanistan</a>` ? I can give you a regex to match _Afghanistan_ and remove the a open and close tag at the same time. Something you're willing to try ?